# How to delete non-existant work/school account from windows 10 local account

Tags: windows-10

Windows 10 keeps telling me that an account connected to my PC's local login account needs to be "fixed", but the problem account no longer exists. I cannot "disconnect" it because Windows 10 tells me it does not belong to a domain (which is correct) and refuses to move past that dialog. And I cannot "manage" the account because it does not exist so I can't log into it.

[image]

[image]

How can I delete this account from the PC's local login account? The PC login account was originally created without an online account, and then I logged in to my online account and it got attached. I don't know how the second, broken account got attached, but I get ongoing warnings about it needing to be fixed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Windows' "Your info" select "Sign in with a local account instead" and change your account to a local account. You will have to enter a password for the local account.

This will log you out and then back in using the new password.

Return to "Your Info" and disconnect all the accounts you want to get rid of on either the "Access work or school" page or the "Your Info" page.

When done, return to "Your Info" and sign in with your Microsoft account again.

Comment: I had the same problem but I was already using a local account. I found I had to switch to a Microsoft account then back to a local account before the "disconnect" button finally appeared.

Answer (score 23):

Select "Access work or school" instead of "Email & accounts" Then you can select the work account and you get the Disconnect button.
[Disconnect Work Account - windows 10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TVi8T.png)

My Windows version: Windows 10, 1909.

Comment: Actually this worked for me even though it had been downvoted twice. Slightly wrong, should say **Select "Access work or school" instead of "Email & accounts"**
Then you can select the work account and you get the Disconnect button.

Comment: Thanks A2D for the the typo correction, I will amend it now.
Not sure if the people who down voted checked the Screenshot or if there had the same Windows version.

Comment: I found this was the correct answer for me too and have bumped it up to 0.  Hopefully it will help someone else and go into the positive figure it belongs at.  I had been going crazy with the Email and Accounts section needing me to login to remove the account I can no longer log into, so I hope Microsoft just adds the Disconnect option there (or in the error) sometime, but for now use Settings->Accounts->"Access work or school" to remove access ... a totally logical user journey in someones mind apparently.

Comment: This is definitely the correct answer for removing an account that no longer exists.